# Cannot read property 'Store' with RedisStore and Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I'm experiencing the following error when I try to run my Node.js app:

```
Starting child process with 'node ./app.js'
C:\Users\Julian\OneDrive\Documents\Websites\Node\node_modules\connect-redis\lib\connect-redis.js:33
  var Store = connect.session.Store;
                             ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'Store' of undefined
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Julian\OneDrive\Documents\Websites\Node\node_modules\connect-redis\lib\connect-redis.js:33:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Julian\OneDrive\Documents\Websites\Node\app.js:9:42)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:590:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
Program node ./app.js exited with code 1

Starting child process with 'node ./app.js'
Received SIGINT, killing child process...
Parent process exiting, terminating child...
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? y
```

My package.json file is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "NodeChat",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "stop": "echo not implemented",
    "start": "supervisor ./app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "connect-flash": "0.1.1",
    "connect-redis": "1.4.7",
    "cookie-parser": "1.4.3",
    "ejs": "0.8.5",
    "express": "4.6.1",
    "express-partials": "0.2.0",
    "express-session": "1.14.2",
    "redis": "0.10.1"
  }
}
```

I thought it might be a compatibility issue, but I believe I'm running a compatible version of connect-redis@1.4.7. I have an instance of Redis running.

Answer (score 0):

Updating "connect-redis": "1.4.7" to 1.5.0 solved the problem for me.